# Unknown payload: { "type" : "Ping" } in console when changing css

Tags: css, asp.net, blazor, payload, hot-reload

I am using Visual Studio Community 2022 with latest updates on Windows 11.
I'm helping my friend in a project with Blazor and ASP.NET. My part would be to do the frontend, but it's not working properly recently.

Whenever I change something I expect it to appear in the browser, but instead most of the time I get this error in the console: `Unknown Payload: {"type": "Ping"}` .

When I add `outline: 1px solid red;` it appears perfectly with no problem. But if I try to for example change the color of an element I see the error.

This is the full message:

```
Unknown payload: { "type" : "Ping" } 
connection.onmessage @ aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js:58
```

```
contact:1 Clear-Site-Data header on 'https://localhost:7258/_framework/clear-browser-cache': Cleared data types: "cache".
```

I asked that dumb AI chatGPT 4 to help me but all it did was telling me to update VS. I did.

But obviously it wasn't enough.

All I could find was that it's connected to the hot reload system of VS. But I don't know how or why.

Comment: This looks like an [open issue with the aspnetcore project](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/45041) ... the problem with hot reload when you make changes you should recompile the source again

Comment: I guess chatGPT was give you the right answer  but the releases it's not coming yet wait for next release for now just compile every change could help you!